# Lenovo X120e only boots into windows after dual boot installation

Tags: installation, boot

I possess a lenovo x120e laptop powered with AMD Fusion E-350 processor. As I wish to have a dual boot machine, I installed Ubuntu desktop 11.10 amd64 along side Windows 7 on it. The installation was successful but the while booting instead of grub giving me options to choose which os to boot, my machine directly boots Windows 7. 
I have tried the steps mentioned at the following link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X120e

I successful installation had Legacy and UEFI boot enabled. When I tried installing with only Legacy boot enabled, the installation halts in between.

It would be deeply appreciated if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use easyBCD software to dual boot,please follow this guide

http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu

Most of the times it will work,sometimes this may not work.In that case you can follow this article
http://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/
the second method is somewhat complex but it works for sure i used both methods.